# how to reduce the space between two bars in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have only two columns, I want to reduce the space between the first column and the second column. I searched, but it did not help. My charts as flows:


[image]

I hope to achieve this effect:


[image]

I have only two Columns, but to achieve this goal, I faked three columns, but their nums are all zero.So it looks like two columns, but actually there are five columns.But this is ugly, are there some elegent method?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to set `xAxis.max = 4` ? You want to display five categories, and since categories are counted from 0, max=4 is what you need, I think.

Comment: I set xAxis.max = 4 and everything is OK, thank you very much @Pawel Fus